# Delete files on FTP site using Webclient and powershell

Tags: powershell, ftp, webclient

I found this code on Stackoverflow to get files from an FTP site using Powershell.
It works great, then only thing I want to do is delete the files from the FPT site after I download them.
Is there an easy modification to this script to do that?
Thanks

```
  #FTP Server Information - SET VARIABLES
$ftp = "ftp://XXX.com/" 
$user = 'UserName' 
$pass = 'Password'
$folder = 'FTP_Folder'
$target = "C:\Folder\Folder1\"

#SET CREDENTIALS
$credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $pass)

function Get-FtpDir ($url,$credentials) {
    $request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $request.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
    if ($credentials) { $request.Credentials = $credentials }
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $response.GetResponseStream() 
    $reader.ReadToEnd()
    $reader.Close()
    $response.Close()
}

#SET FOLDER PATH
$folderPath= $ftp + "/" + $folder + "/"

$Allfiles=Get-FTPDir -url $folderPath -credentials $credentials
$files = ($Allfiles -split "`r`n")

$files 

$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient 
$webclient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user,$pass) 
$counter = 0
foreach ($file in ($files | where {$_ -like "*.txt"})){
    $source=$folderPath + $file  
    $destination = $target + $file 
    $webclient.DownloadFile($source, $target+$file)

    #PRINT FILE NAME AND COUNTER
    $counter++
    $counter
    $source
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint. Your Method is `[System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory`. See here what other methods are available: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4):

I created a new function to do the deletes after I get each file

```
function Del-File($url,$credentials) {
    $request2 = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $request2.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::DeleteFile
    if ($credentials) { $request2.Credentials = $credentials }
    $response2 = $request2.GetResponse()
}
```